# Why the norm of this vector is 1?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

let $f\in C^1(B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$,  $x,x_0$ in the open B and $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$ if we choose $v=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{||f(x)-f(x_0)||}$ then $||v||=1$ why?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question? Its just a vector divided by its magnitude - which will be a unit vector for whatever vector $\vec{v}$ is (barring the zero vector).

Comment: $\|v\|=\left\|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|}\right\|=\cdots=?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because$$\left\lVert\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{\lVert f(x)-f(x_0)\rVert}\right\rVert=\frac1{\lVert f(x)-f(x_0)\rVert}\lVert f(x)-f(x_0)\rVert=1.$$

Comment: Thanks José, I kinda did that but I thought I was wrong..